# split values from angularjs http request success(data)

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

i am trying to get data from php server using angularjs http i user codeigniter as server side 
here is my codeigniter controller

```
 public function searchuser() {

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data["users"] = $this->user_model->getuserpro($request->email);

  print_r($data);
}
```

here is my codeigniter model

```
`function getuserpro($uid) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where("user", array("email" => $uid));
       return $query->result();
    }`
```

here is my angular controller

```
`angular.module('starter').controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, $state, userlog, $http) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://mydomain/Home/searchuser",
        data: {
            email: userlog.email,
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });

    /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
    request.success(function(data) {

        document.getElementById("namemy").textContent = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

` 
when i log data it's like this

```
    "Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [iduser] => 171
                    [email] => chhdshfh@gmail.com
                    [password] => 123
                    [fname] => cha
                    [lname] => shm
                    [dbth] => 1989-08-19 00:00:00
                    [addone] => aaaaaaaa
                    [addtwo] => cccccccccccc
                    [city] => bbbbbbbbbbbbb
                    [country] => LK
                    [tp] => 0111111111
                    [currency] => LKR
                    [gender] => A
                    [job] => sdfsdf
                )

        )

)
"
```

how can i split this array  and  assign value to separate  variable  like  id,email,password,fname,lname i tried like this

```
 ` $scope.id=data.iduser;
        $scope.email=data.email;
        $scope.pass=data.password;
        $scope.fname=data.fname;
        $scope.lname=data.lname;`
```

that's  not working  please any  one help

Comment: Try sending and receiving data in JSON format. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Its always good to use $query->result_array() because it is faster and returns pure array instead of array of objects. from controller convert into json and pass it to angular which makes easier to assign the values to scope

Comment: convert    data  response to  jason   is that  what you  mean   Rajesh 1  ?

Comment: Rajesh1   thankyou   for  your   tip   i  convert     $query->result_array()   to  json  object      using  json_encode();  that   works    thank you   for   your help