# Get values from array

Tags: javascript

How to  get values  as  fname,lname separately  from  this array  using javascript

```
       "Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [iduser] => 171
                    [email] => chhdshfh@gmail.com
                    [password] => 123
                    [fname] => cha
                    [lname] => shm
                    [dbth] => 1989-08-19 00:00:00
                    [addone] => aaaaaaaa
                    [addtwo] => cccccccccccc
                    [city] => bbbbbbbbbbbbb
                    [country] => LK
                    [tp] => 0111111111
                    [currency] => LKR
                    [gender] => A
                    [job] => sdfsdf
                )

        )

)
"
```

this is http response success  data object  i want  to get values separately please anyone  help

Comment: In which format this response is? this is not a JSON for sure. what is this?

Comment: from where you get/copied this response?

Comment: Do you receive the response from ROR application? Can you explain a little bit further on how do you intend to fetch the HTTP response and how actually the response looks like?

Comment: can you  help   mike  please    this   is  my   question   early      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362961/split-values-from-angularjs-http-request-successdata

Answer (score 0):

This should be an PHP array. You should convert it to JSON format and set the propreate header in PHP.

```
<?php
$your_array = array(
        ['users'] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        ['iduser'] => 171,
                        ['email'] => 'chhdshfh@gmail.com',
                        ['password'] => 123,
                        ['fname'] => 'cha',
                        ['lname'] => 'shm',
                        ['dbth'] => '1989-08-19 00:00:00',
                        ['addone'] => 'aaaaaaaa',
                        ['addtwo'] => 'cccccccccccc',
                        ['city'] => 'bbbbbbbbbbbbb',
                        ['country'] => 'LK',
                        ['tp'] => 0111111111
                        ['currency'] => 'LKR',
                        ['gender'] => 'A',
                        ['job'] => 'sdfsdf'
                    )

            )
    );

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Comment: yes   that    works   koredalin    thank   you  for   your   help     i  convert                                 $query->result_array()   to  json  object      using  json_encode();  that   works.   mike,              Tao P. R. thank you   for   your help